# How do I use the .so file from .aar of a library module in another application module?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, .so

I have a .so file built into the .aar of a library project. How do I use this .so file and only the .so file in another application module of the same project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include aar files used in library projects in main project in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936092/how-to-include-aar-files-used-in-library-projects-in-main-project-in-android)

Comment: No.I have a application module which needs to be compiled alongside the library module and the .so from the library module needs to be placed at a certain path in the Application Module so that it links this .so file.How do i do it?